# Adding same drop-down value to multiple cells simultaneously

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I was wondering how to add the same drop-down value (e.g. Yes or No) to multiple cells in the column at the same time? I tried selecting individual cells that I need to fill with the same value using Ctrl, and then selecting the value from the drop-down menu, but it only fills the single highlighted cell.

Is there a quick way to select cells and then add the same drop-down value simultaneously to all of them?

I'm using Excel 2013.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Place the drop-down in the top cell.  Then select the block of cells (including the top cell) with either the ARROW keys or the mouse and touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, but then again I didn't quite understand what you mean. I have a column of cells, and all have a drop-down menu with two values. I would like to select a certain number of those cells and input the same value to all of them at the same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i also found no answers for this online so came up with my own solution.

It is using macros but only a basic knowledge of how to record is needed so its very easy.

Once your drop down lists are set up, you would start with Sheet 1 and simply record a macro where you are copying the value you selected in sheet 1 and then pasting into sheet 2. then assign this macro to a button on sheet 1. every time you click the button, it will copy and paste the selected value in your sheet 1 drop down into sheet 2.

you would then do the same thing in sheet 2, except that you are copying the value into sheet 1.

you can do this for any number of sheets.

hth.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as follows and it worked:
Select a cell and select the value for it (yes or no for example). Then select the group of cells you wan to have that same value - include the original cells with the value (yes or no)as the top cell in the range. Hit ctrl and D and all the cells will fill with the value in the top cell.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this task in Excel 2013 by doing the following:

1. Select the cell with the drop down response
2. Scroll down to the last cell in the row that you want to have the same answer
3. Press the shift key
4. Select the last cell in the row that you want to have the same response
5. Release shift key and scroll back up to the first cell that you highlighted
6. Select your response in that cell
7. Hit Ctrl+D (to duplicate response).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and explain a little more clearly for you.

Select, with your mouse, the top most cell in the column you want to make all YES, scroll down if you need to and then, before clicking anything hold the SHIFT (not CTRL) key while you click the bottom cell in the row you wish to update.

This should highlight all of the cells in the column from the first, to the last you clicked. Now, release the SHIFT key and select YES (or no) in the top cell. The top cell (only) will change to YES (or No if you selected that). Now, without clicking doing anything else, hold down CTRL and while holding it press D.

If done correctly, all of the highlighted cells will now match the top cell.