# Filling a range of cells with the same value using drop-down list

Tags: excel, vba

We all know that Excel has some counter-intuitive behaviours and it is, I believe, one of them:

**When you select a range of few cells, starting your selection with the cell with data validation list and choose value from drop-down list: only one cell changes (the one containing drop-down list) instead of all selected.**

[image: visualisation]

Sometimes a few magic keyboard shortcuts such as CTRL+d, or combination of CTRL+' and CTRL+ENTER can fix this behaviour, but from my experience clients doesn't like to learn some new hacks, they just want to work everything in as simple way as possible.

I found even similar questions on SO e.g. here:

[Adding same drop-down value to multiple cells simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018697/)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very simple code, but following few lines of code make my life easier, and I am sure this will help somebody too. Code in Worksheet module of course:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' MACRO FILLS THE WHOLE SELECTED RANGE
    ' WITH THE SAME VALUE USING DROP-DOWN LIST
    ' IN JUST ONE ACTIVE CELL
    
    ' change to false if all selected cells should be filled with value
    Const FILL_VISIBLE_CELLS_ONLY As Boolean = True
    
    ' detecting if dropdown list was used
    '
    '   I am using very clever solution by JvdV from SO
    '       ~~~~> stackoverflow.com/questions/56942551/
    '
    '   If after edit we're in the same cell - drop-down list was used
    '   I know that may be also drag&drop or copy-paste
    '   but it seems no matters here.
    '   Warning! Should be add one more check if someone used 
    '   'accept OK character' next to formula bar, not implemented here.
    '
    If ActiveCell.Address <> Target.Address Then Exit Sub
    
    ' preventing error which sometimes occurs
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' fill a range or visible range with activeCell value
    If FILL_VISIBLE_CELLS_ONLY Then
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Else
        Selection.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
        
End Sub
```

[image: visualisation]

Answer (score 0):

When you select a `Range` of more than one `Cell`, is is important to distinguish between the `Active Cell` (the single highlighted cell) and the `Selection` (the entire selected range, including the `Active Cell`).

Then:

- Any `Content` (such as `Values` or `Formulas`) that you enter into the `Formula bar` is input into the `Active Cell` only, not the entire `Selection`.
- Any `Formatting` changes you make are applied to the entire `Selection`, not just the `Active Cell`.
- An exception is when entering an `Array formula` which applies to the `Selection`.

Since in this case you are making a change to `content` not `formatting`, it is applied to only the `Active Cell`.

When considering the above, it is not counterintuitive but entirely consistent with the design and operation of the software.

However, from a UX experience this may seem counterintuitive simply because it defies your expectation. This is kind of like a "customer is always right" type situation, which can be very frustrating for programmers, but is essential that it be understood. You can read more about the concept in a series of well-written articles on the topic at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/10/controlling-your-environment-makes-you-happy/ (disclosure: the author of these articles happens to be integral to the development history of both Excel and SO, but it is linked here on merit). It was written more than 20 years ago and is still every bit as relevant today.